# @ModelAttribute getting null values from ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am having a controller method to accept a model from front end(ajax post).

The controller is as follows,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/lead_post", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody Response create_Task(ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute("lead_post") LeadModal leadmodal,HttpSession ses)
{
```

The ajax Post request is as follows,

```
 $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url : "/biz/lead_post",
             data : { 
                 clientName : $('#clientName').val(),
                 companyName : $('#companyName').val(),
                 contactNumber : $('#contactNumber').val(),
                 address : $('#address_').val(),
                 meetingDate : $('#meetingDate').val(),
                 meetingTime : $('#meetingTime').val(),
                 productsDealingWith : $('#productsDealingWith').val(),
                 nadInCharge : $('#nad_dropdown').val,
        },
            success : function(data) {



            },
            error: function(e) {

                alert("error"+e.Message);
            }
        });
```

The LeadModal is as follows,

```
public class LeadModal {

private String clientName;
private String companyName;
private Long contactNumber;
private String address;
private Date meetingDate;
private Time meetingTime;
private String productsDealingWith;
private Integer nadInCharge;
private Integer tmeInCharge;
private String status;
private Integer nadAcceptanceStatus;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public Integer getNadAcceptanceStatus() {
    return nadAcceptanceStatus;
}
public void setNadAcceptanceStatus(Integer nadAcceptanceStatus) {
    this.nadAcceptanceStatus = nadAcceptanceStatus;
}
......
```

I have a similar functionality working, but over here the model is showing all null values when the ajax post is fired. I also tried to manually send the POST request using postman tool, but it still shows the null values. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is `LeadModal`? You have posted class `Leads`. Is `LeadModal` extending `Leads`? Can you show it, please?

Comment: Sorry alfope, I posted the wrong class, here is the correct one

Comment: It looks fine.If you are not getting an error it is difficult to say. I guess there is an error when doing the binding. What if you just send the clientName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was a mismatch in the format of Date between the date sent by ajax post(i.e. yyyy-mm-dd) and the date received by LeadModal.

I had to declare the date format in LeadModal to accept the format of yyyy-mm-dd like this,

```
private @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date meetingDate;
```

Because of one mismatched parameter the @ModelAttribute was unable to map the model with front end ajax post.